How to make a forest plots of diagnostic accuracy?
I want to make a forest plot which contains sensitivity and specificity together.
Here is my example data and script:
study_data <- data.frame(
  Study = c("Study 1", "Study 2", "Study 3", "Study 4", "Study 5"),
  TP = c(29, 25, 170, 63, 136),
  FP = c(1, 0, 54, 13, 53),
  FN = c(55, 18, 121, 27, 53),
  TN = c(592, 77, 745, 159, 293)
)

# Calculate sensitivity and specificity
study_data$Sensitivity <- study_data$TP / (study_data$TP + study_data$FN)
study_data$Specificity <- study_data$TN / (study_data$TN + study_data$FP)

# Calculate the logit transformations and standard errors for sensitivity and specificity
study_data$Logit_Sensitivity <- log(study_data$Sensitivity / (1 - study_data$Sensitivity))
study_data$Logit_Specificity <- log(study_data$Specificity / (1 - study_data$Specificity))
study_data$SE_Sensitivity <- sqrt(1 / study_data$TP + 1 / study_data$FN)
study_data$SE_Specificity <- sqrt(1 / study_data$TN + 1 / study_data$FP)

# Remove non-finite values
study_data <- study_data[is.finite(study_data$Logit_Sensitivity) & is.finite(study_data$Logit_Specificity),]
# Calculate 95% Confidence Intervals for sensitivity and specificity
study_data$Sens_Lower_CI <- study_data$Sensitivity - 1.96 * study_data$SE_Sensitivity
study_data$Sens_Upper_CI <- study_data$Sensitivity + 1.96 * study_data$SE_Sensitivity
study_data$Spec_Lower_CI <- study_data$Specificity - 1.96 * study_data$SE_Specificity
study_data$Spec_Upper_CI <- study_data$Specificity + 1.96 * study_data$SE_Specificity

# Sensitivity meta-analysis
sensitivity_meta <- rma(yi = study_data$Logit_Sensitivity, sei = study_data$SE_Sensitivity, method = "REML")
# Specificity meta-analysis
specificity_meta <- rma(yi = study_data$Logit_Specificity, sei = study_data$SE_Specificity, method = "REML")


# Determine the number of rows dynamically based on the processed data
num_rows <- nrow(study_data)

# Sensitivity forest plot
forest_sens <- forest(sensitivity_meta, atransf = exp, at = log(c(0.01, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.99)),
                      xlim = c(-10, 5), ilab = cbind(study_data$TP, study_data$FN), ilab.xpos = c(-9, -7),
                      cex = 0.75, order = order(study_data$Study), rows = 1:num_rows,
                      xlab = "Sensitivity", slab = study_data$Study, mlab = "RE Model for Sensitivity")
forest_sens
# Adding text for column headers
text(-10, num_rows + 1, "Study", pos = 4, cex = 0.75)
text(-9, num_rows + 1, "TP", pos = 4, cex = 0.75)
text(-7, num_rows + 1, "FN", pos = 4, cex = 0.75)

# Specificity forest plot
forest_spec <- forest(specificity_meta, atransf = exp, at = log(c(0.01, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.99)),
                      xlim = c(-10, 5), ilab = cbind(study_data$TN, study_data$FP), ilab.xpos = c(-9, -7),
                      cex = 0.75, order = order(study_data$Study), rows = 1:num_rows,
                      xlab = "Specificity", slab = study_data$Study, mlab = "RE Model for Specificity")

# Adding text for column headers
text(-10, num_rows + 1, "Study", pos = 4, cex = 0.75)
text(-9, num_rows + 1, "TN", pos = 4, cex = 0.75)
text(-7, num_rows + 1, "FP", pos = 4, cex = 0.75)

However, I tried several methods, all of these results are not what I want.
The figure I want is below.
I am not sure if I can make it by R or python or other software ?
Many thanks in advance.


Anybody here could give me some advice ?
